# What is a good reason to store data in hex in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, hex

I've encountered some UNICODE stored in hex with a view that fails to convert it. I've since worked with a colleague to decode said information. Which as it turns out is some rather lengthy sentences being stored in a single column.

TL; DR: What are some good reasons for storing text this way? The only answer I could come up with is one of economy. Maximizing the storage capacity of a column, that is. Are there other reasons?

How I extracted the data:

```
SELECT COLUMN_1
    , COLUMN_2
    , COLUMN_3
    , CAST(CAST(HEX_DATA_COLUMN AS VARBINARY(128)) AS NVARCHAR(128)) AS DECODED_hex_WOWZERS
FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: It could be from a pre-2012 database, and that was how they stored unicode data?

Comment: I once saw people storing text as Varbinary (which isn't actually hexadecimal) for obfuscation of the contents from a casual browser... which was stupid, but true.

Comment: Note that "maximizing storage capacity" is a bit misleading, because apparently you can tweak things by changing the collation (ie, you can apparently flat out store UTF-8 data in a regular `CHAR(n)`, since the type _stores one byte_)